# "sich schaden" mit Akk.- oder Dat. Ergänzung?

Tags: grammar

Ich habe eine Frage, wie sagt man in DEU:

> Du schadest dir der Gesundheit

oder

> Du schadest dir die Gesundheit

Das Verb "schaden" ist mit Dat. Ergänzung, also ist das reflexive Pronomen im Dativ, aber ich mit dem reflexive Pronomen kapiere nicht, wann das Objekt im Akkusativ (die Gesundheit) oder Dativ (der Gesundheit) ist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Schaden* kann nur ein Objekt haben (im Dativ), deshalb kann man den Satz

> Du schadest dir.

nicht um ein weiteres Objekt erweitern (weder im Dativ noch im Akkusativ). Es muss stattdessen

> Du schadest deiner Gesundheit.

heißen.

Comment: Interessant! Ich wusste das nicht, danke :) !

Comment: Es geht noch: „Du schadest Dir gesundheitlich.“

Answer (score 5):

*Sich schaden* kann gar kein weiteres Objekt im Akkusativ oder Dativ haben. (Es ist auch die Frage, ob man es überhaupt als reflexives Verb bezeichnen kann. Die üblichen Tests besteht es nicht: Man kann etwas anderes als Objekt einsetzen und *Wem schadet X?* fragen.) Wenn man die Gesundheit im Satz unterbringen will, muß man sagen:

> Du schadest deiner Gesundheit.